# Creating get/set accessors for a cli::array property

Tags: class, properties, c++-cli, accessor

I am fairly new to c++/cli and I have created a custom class that has two 2d arrays as a properties. I am having trouble creating the get/set for these properties. I have tried a few different ways of defining the get/set, but haven't succeed yet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public ref class MyClass {
public:
    cli::array<bool, 2>^ filled;
    cli::array<System::String^,2> ^id;

    MyClass() {
        filled = gcnew cli::array<bool,2 > (8, 12);
        id = gcnew cli::array<System::String^, 2>(8, 12);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (size_t z = 0; z < 12; i++)
            {
                filled[(int)i, (int)z] = false; // this line currently gives the error: no instance of function "cli::array<T,rank>::set[with T=bool, rank=2]" matches the argument list
            }
        }
    };
    property bool default[int, int]{
        bool get(int a, int b) {
            return filled[a,b];
        }
        void set(int a, int b, bool value) {
            filled[a,b] = value;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Use the `default` keyword.  It is spelt-out with an example on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f1ec0b1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I have added the get/set for the first property. I get a conflict if I add another one for the second property. Do I have to do something different for the second one?

Comment: Sure, you can have only one default property.  It also supports indexed properties, they have a name other than "default".  Same page.